# Linking cookies and global variables in the game Project Zomboid

Tags: lua

I want to link my IDE vs code to the project Zomboid game for writing mods, and help with autocomplete and syntax highlighting.

Turning to the Internet , I was advised to download Lua Language Server , create a file called setup lua in the root of the game . With such content

```
package.path = package.path .. ";./media/lua/?.lua;./media/lua/?/init.lua"
package.cpath = package.cpath .. ";./clibs/?.dll;./clibs/?.so"

dofile("C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/common/ProjectZomboid/mods/Fractions/media/lua/client/ISUI/FractionUserPanelUI.lua")


require "ISUI/ISPanel"
require "ISUI/ISButton"
require "ISUI/ISComboBox"
require "ISUI/ISCollapsableWindow"
require "ISUI/ISPanelJoypad"
require "ISUI/ISLabel"
require "ISUI/ISContextMenu"
require "ISUI/getPlayerHud"
require "ISUI/Events"
require "ISUI/getFileReader"
require "ISUI/getCore"
require "ISUI/UIFont"
require "ISUI/UIManager"
require "ISUI/getPlayer"
require "ISUI/ISInventoryPaneContextMenu"
require "ISUI/getTextManager"
```

And in the very fashion to make a binding

```
dofile "C:/Program Files(x86)/Steam/steamapps/common/ProjectZomboid/setup.lua"
```

Unfortunately, this does not work, and I found another way out, it is to create a folder in the project with the name.vs code and the settings file.json with such content:

```
    "files.encoding": "windows1251",
    "files.autoGuessEncoding": true,
    "Lua.workspace.library": {
        "./lua": true
    },
    "Lua.workspace.libraryWithSubmodules": {
        "./mods": {
            "module1": true,
            "module2": true,
            "module3": true
        },
        "./lua": true
    },
    "Lua.diagnostics.globals": [
        "getWorld"
]
}
```

It doesn't help either, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to find out how to handle `/` or `\` depending on the OS the Interpreter runs.
For example, a single Backslash inside double Quotes producing an Escape Sequence Error and therefore it has to be escaped with another Backslash.
Like...

```
wpath = "C:\\Temp\\Lua"
```

Single Backslash (and Whitespace like Space) is possible with...

```
wpath = [[C:\Temp\Lua]]
```

Also i like to wrote: Use `.` instead of `/` or `\` in `require()`

```
require "ISUI.ISPanel"
```

That should work OS independently.